# Having trouble creating trigger that updates column based on variable

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, database-trigger

I'm trying to create a trigger for a class that updates customer balance depending on how many days late or early the item was returned. I have a charter table that has a due date and return date, the trigger is designed to only fire when the return date is being updated. The trigger then takes the difference between return date and due date and stores that value into a variable. I have a series of if else statements that determine whether the item was returned late or early and then multiply the number of days by the late fee or early bonus. Then it updates the customer balance in the customer table to whatever the value of the fee variable is. Oracle is saying I have a syntax error on my end statement and I'm not sure what is wrong.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Fee_Trigger
AFTER UPDATE ON CHARTER
FOR EACH ROW 
WHEN ((:NEW.Return_Date <> :OLD.Return_Date AND :NEW.Return_Date IS NOT 
NULL))
DECLARE
Fee NUMBER; 
BEGIN 
Fee := (:NEW.Return_Date - Due_Date); 
IF Fee > 0 THEN Fee := (Fee * 75) ;
ELSE IF Fee < 0 THEN Fee := (Fee * 25);
ELSE IF Fee = 0 THEN FEE := Fee;
END IF;
UPDATE CUSTOMER 
SET Customer_Balance = Fee
WHERE CustomerID = :NEW.CustomerID
END;
```

Comment: UPDATE statement is not ended with a semi-colon.

Comment: Your code makes no sense on a naive reading.  The difference between two dates is going to be an interval type.  It is highly suspicious assigning an interval type to a column called `customer_balance`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some little formatting errors. The following may be used, alternatively :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Fee_Trigger
AFTER UPDATE ON CHARTER
FOR EACH ROW 
WHEN ((NEW.Return_Date <> OLD.Return_Date AND NEW.Return_Date IS NOT NULL))
DECLARE
 Fee NUMBER; 
BEGIN 
 Fee := :NEW.Return_Date - :NEW.Due_Date; 

 IF    Fee > 0 THEN Fee := (Fee * 75); 
 ELSIF Fee < 0 THEN Fee := (Fee * 25);
 ELSIF Fee = 0 THEN Fee := Fee;
 END IF;

 UPDATE CUSTOMER 
    SET Customer_Balance = Fee
  WHERE CustomerID = :NEW.CustomerID;

END;
```

The following issues encountered :

- Due_date was not defined (`:OLD.Due_Date` or `:NEW.Due_Date` may be used)
- `ELSIF` should be used instead of `ELSE IF`
- `UPDATE` statement should be ended with a `semicolon`.
- Remove `colons` before `OLD` and `NEW` inside `WHEN` statement.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I didn't notice the missing semicolon and forgot that it's elsif. However, now Oracle gives me an error when I try to compile saying invalid use of a bind variable in the When clause. Also I don't think I need to declare Due_Date as that date is already predefined in the charter table before inserting the return_date. Could you explain why I shouldn't use integer of date difference for the update? By using the difference I get the days late/early and multiply them by there respective fee/refund.

Comment: @Vanir OK, the logic behind is your choice. I edited for other problems (I converted Due_Date to :NEW.Due_Date, since you told that CHARTER has that column).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest replacing the `IF/ELSIF` statements with a CASE expression in the UPDATE statement:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Fee_Trigger
  AFTER UPDATE ON CHARTER
  FOR EACH ROW 
  WHEN ((:NEW.Return_Date <> :OLD.Return_Date AND :NEW.Return_Date IS NOT NULL))
DECLARE
  Due_Date                      DATE := TRUNC(SYSDATE); -- initialization as an example value.
  nDays_between_return_and_due  NUMBER;
BEGIN
  nDays_between_return_and_due := TRUNC(:NEW.Return_Date - Due_Date);

  UPDATE CUSTOMER 
    SET Customer_Balance = CASE
                             WHEN nDays_between_return_and_due > 0 THEN  -- Returned late
                               nDays_between_return_and_due * 75
                             WHEN nDays_between_return_and_due < 0 THEN  -- Returned early
                               nDays_between_return_and_due * 25
                             ELSE  -- Returned on time
                               0
                           END
    WHERE CustomerID = :NEW.CustomerID;
END FEE_TRIGGER;
```

Best of luck.